# Subscribe to tag and get only non-answered questions

Tags: support, subscription

I've subscribed to a couple of tags and I'm getting these daily e-mail digests. However, 80% of questions in these digests are already answered - there's no point for me to waste time opening them (trying to answer) just to understand that it's already answered.

Is there some way to ensure that digest questions in tag subscription email would contain only non-answered questions (at the time of sending an e-mail, of course - I understand that you can't control what happens after e-mail being sent)